# SMIE and backward-up-list

Tags: smie

Though SMIE seems to be indenting my little language very nicely, and `forward-sexp` also works well, I don't get `backward-up-list` working as desired.

My grammar:

```
(defvar holscript-smie-grammar
  (smie-prec2->grammar
   (smie-bnf->prec2
    '((id)
      (decl ("Theorem" id ":" quotedmaterial "Proof" tactic "QED")
            ("Definition" id ":" quotedmaterial "Termination" tactic "End")
            ("Definition" id ":" quotedmaterial "End")
            ("Datatype:" quotedmaterial "End"))
      (quotedmaterial)
      (tactic (tactic ">>" tactic)
              (tactic "\\\\" tactic)
              (tactic ">-" tactic)
              (tactic ">|" tactic)))
    '((assoc ">>" "\\\\" ">-"  ">|")))))
```

If I have my cursor inside a `Theorem` (at `*` below, say):

```
Theorem name:  
  statement
Proof
  tactic1 `*` >> tactic2
QED
```

then I can navigate along the tactics nicely.  If I have the cursor on `Theorem` I can use `C-M-b` to navigate a sequence of `Theorem`s nicely too.  But if I'm between the `Proof` and `QED` keywords (or the `Theorem` and `Proof` keywords), I can't use `backward-up-list` to get me to the top level of that phrase.  Instead, I get a `Scan error: "Unbalanced parentheses"`, and I shoot to the top of the whole file.

It seems to me as if the grammar is defining the `Theorem`-`Proof`-`QED` syntax as a sexp-like thing (and wrt to `forward-sexp` this also seems true), but `backward-up-list` doesn't seem to agree...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known bug (aka limitation) of SMIE's support for `(backward-)up-list`.  To fix it right we need to make changes to `(backward-)up-list`, or otherwise redirect those commands to SMIE versions of them.

IIRC, you can partly avoid the problem by replacing things like

```
(decl
 ...
 ("Theorem" id ":" quotedmaterial "Proof" tactic "QED")
 ...)
```

with something like:

```
(decl
 ...
 ("Theorem" theorem-contents "QED")
 ...)
(theorem-contents
 (theorem-head "Proof" tactic))
(theorem-head (id ":" quotedmaterial))
```

Comment: Thanks for that; I will hack together a poor man’s approximation.

Comment: @MichaelNorrish: I added a suggestion that can sometimes work around the problem.

Comment: Thanks!  That has definitely helped!